# After closeing MMDrawer Controller which view controller life cycle method will called in swift4?

Tags: ios, xcode, uitabbarcontroller, swift4, mmdrawercontroller

i have a tab bar controller, and inside that tab bar i have five view controller. i also have have a right view controller(drawer) which is on homeVC. for rightViewController i use MMDrawerController source: https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=1468&v=TdKnImb4SWs. in the appdelegate . Now when the right view controller is closed, which life cycle of view controller is getting called? because i want to write a function. I have used this code on appdelegate

```
    let rightViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "RightViewVC") as! RightViewVC



       UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor : UIColor.white]

    let rightSideMenuNav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: rightViewController)
    drawerController = MMDrawerController(center:mainPage,rightDrawerViewController:rightSideMenuNav)

   // drawerController!.openDrawerGestureModeMask = MMOpenDrawerGestureMode.panningCenterView
    drawerController!.closeDrawerGestureModeMask = MMCloseDrawerGestureMode.panningCenterView
    drawerController!.closeDrawerGestureModeMask = MMCloseDrawerGestureMode.all
    drawerController!.preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation = MMDrawerOpenCenterInteractionMode.full

    window?.rootViewController = drawerController
```

Comment: there is one block which is called when you close the drawer

Comment: which block sir?

Comment: For opening drawer i think you write this method `self.drawer?.close(.left, animated: isAnimation) { (isCompleted) in
           
        }` so when drawer successfully open then completion handler will called.

Comment: for opeining drawer i have written  let appdelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
        
        appdelegate.drawerController?.toggle(MMDrawerSide.right, animated: true, completion: nil)

Comment: my bad checked my updated comment

Comment: actually my right view controller is the filter screen, so when i click on filter i want to show the updated search result on homescreen, but unable to send data from RightView VC to homeVC

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176923/discussion-between-chirag-shah-and-gorib-developer).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176932/discussion-between-chirag-shah-and-gorib-developer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MMDrawer provide the completion block when open,close or toggel the drawer you just need to compare the event like drawer is close or open you got the success. Here is the code

```
@IBAction func rightMenuButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) { 

    let appdelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate 

    appdelegate.drawerController?.toggle(MMDrawerSide.right, animated: true){ (isCompleted) in 
            if appdelegate.drawerController?.openSide == MMDrawerSide.none 
            { 
                 print("drawer close")
                 if let objHome = appdelegate.drawerController?.centerViewController as? HomeVC{ 
                      print("Got Home VC") 
                 }  
            } 
            else if appdelegate.drawerController?.openSide == MMDrawerSide.right 
            { 
                 print("drawer open") 
            } 
     }
}
```

Comment: @GoribDeveloper yes what is issue?

Comment: sir i am failed to sent data from RightviewVC to homeVC

Comment: @GoribDeveloper i help you till find you home vc now it totally logical part that how to pass data to that controller. Take help of any senior person

Answer (score 1):

the `viewwillApear()` in homeViewController will get called when rightViewController closed.

Comment: Thanks for reply sir, but i am giving break point in viewwillApear() after closing the rightView controller it is not getting called

Comment: wait a minute sir

Comment: this code i have written in a button which is in the RightViewController

 let appdelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate

       appdelegate.drawerController?.closeDrawer(animated: true, completion: nil)

Comment: actually my right view controller is the filter screen, so when i click on filter i want to show the updated search result on homescreen, but unable to send data from RightView VC to homeVC

Answer (score 0):

Try to print in each viewDidLoad to see the active controllers:

```
if let window = UIApplication.shared.delegate?.window {
    if var viewController = window?.rootViewController {
        // handle navigation controllers
        if(viewController is UINavigationController){
            viewController = (viewController as! UINavigationController).visibleViewController!
        }
        print(viewController)
    }
}
```

or

```
if self.window.rootViewController is MyViewController {
    //do something if it's an instance of that class
}
```

Comment: actually my right view controller is the filter screen, so when i click on filter i want to show the updated search result on homescreen, but unable to send data from RightView VC to homeVC

Comment: @GoribDeveloper, this video is 3 years old. Have you tried other solutions? What is your goal about view controllers?

Comment: Goal means sir? i have tried other possible ways, i prefer this video bcz it shows drawer with tab bar controller, that;s why